# How to convert c# async library to Synchronous way

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there any recommended way to convert a C# library which is written using async /await pattern to Synchronous way?

Comment: [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) goes into lots of detail, but the short answer is *no*.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? Why don't you use `await` ? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Kanavos i am writing winforms application and need to use api client library which has async pattern.

Comment: @InfoÁsith I repeat, why not use `await`? All supported .NET versions provide `async/await`. Even the unsupported versions like 4.0 allow you to write `.ContinueWith`. You can't use tasks *at all* with 3.5 or earlier

Comment: @InfoÁsith post your actual code and what your problem is in the question itself. As it is, the only answer one can give is `don't do it this way`

Comment: @InfoÁsith have you checked into `async/await` at all? Are you aware that event handlers can use `await` if they have the `async void` syntax?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  ok i changed my mind to use async/await as it is.is that common to use async event handlers in winForms programming

Comment: @InfoÁsith of course. You can't *not* use them actually, if you want async behaviour. That's the only reason the `async void` syntax exists. Check Stephen Cleary's MSDN Magazine article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)